# Problem with modifying the digits in tbl_summary

Tags: gtsummary

I have a problem adjusting the digits for `tbl_summary()`. Here is my code:

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
library(officer)
library(gtsummary)
library(janitor)

### Effect size
my_ES_test <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  aovmod = aov(data[[variable]] ~ data[[by]])
  lsr::etaSquared(aovmod)[1,1]
}

### Standard Error Mean
sem <- function(x){
  sqrt(var(x, na.rm=TRUE)/sum(!is.na(x)))
}

### Pooled Standard Error
PSE <- function(data, variable, by,...) {
  s <- data %>% 
    group_by(!!sym(by)) %>% 
    summarise(s = var(!!sym(variable)), 
              n = n()) %>% 
    mutate(num = s*(n-1))
  psd <- sqrt(sum(s$num)/(sum(s$n) - nrow(s)))
  psd*sqrt(sum(1/s$n))
}

### gtsummary
Iris_data <- iris %>%
  select(names(iris))%>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by = Species,
    digits = all_continuous() ~ c(2,2),
    type = list(everything() ~ "continuous"),
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ± {sem}",
    label = list(Sepal.Length = "Sepal Length", 
                 Sepal.Width = "Sepal Width", 
                 Petal.Length = "Petal Length",
                 Petal.Width = "Petal Width")
  ) %>%
  add_stat(fns = all_continuous() ~ PSE) %>% 
  add_stat(fns = all_continuous() ~ my_ES_test) %>% 
  add_p(
    test = all_continuous() ~ "aov", pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 3)
  ) %>% 
  modify_header(label = "**Size**", p.value = "**p-value**", add_stat_1 = "**PSE**", add_stat_2 = "**\U03B7\U00B2**") %>%
  modify_footnote(add_stat_1 = "Pooled Standard Error", abbreviation = FALSE) %>%
  bold_levels() %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  as_flex_table()
```

In general the table works perfectly fine. However, if I moved the p-value above `add_stat(fns = all_continuous() ~ PSE)` then the p-value digits will change back to it's original format without three digits. Is it a way to fix this? Also, I cannot adjust the digits for the PSE for some reasons using the `purrr::partial(style_ratio, digits = 3)`. Trying over and over but still cannot solve the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `modify_fmt_fun()` function to modify the function that format/style the columns. Is this what you're asking?

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(officer)
library(gtsummary)
#> #BlackLivesMatter

### Effect size
my_ES_test <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  aovmod = aov(data[[variable]] ~ data[[by]])
  lsr::etaSquared(aovmod)[1,1]
}

### Standard Error Mean
sem <- function(x){
  sqrt(var(x, na.rm=TRUE)/sum(!is.na(x)))
}

### Pooled Standard Error
PSE <- function(data, variable, by,...) {
  s <- data %>% 
    group_by(!!sym(by)) %>% 
    summarise(s = var(!!sym(variable)), 
              n = n()) %>% 
    mutate(num = s*(n-1))
  psd <- sqrt(sum(s$num)/(sum(s$n) - nrow(s)))
  psd*sqrt(sum(1/s$n))
}

### gtsummary
iris %>%
  select(names(iris))%>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by = Species,
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ± {sem}"
  ) %>% 
  add_p(
    test = all_continuous() ~ "aov", 
    pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 3)
  ) %>%
  add_stat(fns = all_continuous() ~ PSE) %>% 
  add_stat(fns = all_continuous() ~ my_ES_test)  %>% 
  modify_header(label = "**Size**", p.value = "**p-value**", add_stat_1 = "**PSE**", add_stat_2 = "**\U03B7\U00B2**") %>%
  modify_footnote(add_stat_1 = "Pooled Standard Error", abbreviation = FALSE) %>%
  modify_fmt_fun( c(add_stat_1, add_stat_2) ~ purrr::partial(style_sigfig, digits = 5)) %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Size** | **setosa**, N = 50 | **versicolor**, N = 50 | **virginica**, N = 50 | **p-value** | **PSE** | **η²** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sepal.Length | 5.01 ± 0.05 | 5.94 ± 0.07 | 6.59 ± 0.09 | <0.001 | 0.12610 | 0.61871 |
| Sepal.Width | 3.43 ± 0.05 | 2.77 ± 0.04 | 2.97 ± 0.05 | <0.001 | 0.08321 | 0.40078 |
| Petal.Length | 1.46 ± 0.02 | 4.26 ± 0.07 | 5.55 ± 0.08 | <0.001 | 0.10541 | 0.94137 |
| Petal.Width | 0.25 ± 0.01 | 1.33 ± 0.03 | 2.03 ± 0.04 | <0.001 | 0.05013 | 0.92888 |

<sup>Created on 2022-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Dr. Sjoberg. Yes, that is what exactly what I am looking for! Thank you so much for your quick response!